# .htaccess to add ?product_view=list

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

My WooCommerce platform show grid view by default, but I need it as list. This could be achieved by adding "?product_view=list" to the end of url of my categories.

So, it is looking like this:

```
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-1/
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-2/
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-3/
```

etc.

And it should look like this:

```
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-1/?product_view=list
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-2/?product_view=list
subdomain.mydomain.com/shop/category-3/?product_view=list
```

Any help on how to do it via .htaccess instead of using plugins?
Thanks in advance!

p.s. My current .htaccess file also contain following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What are your current .htaccess rules?

Comment: Nothing special, usual WordPress things like:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: add it to the question

Comment: This seems like a roundabout solution. Why not just change the default display of the products via the theme?

Comment: There is no such option in theme settings. Theme creator decided to give that choice to the visitor exclusively, and grid view is set as default.